# Passing additional arguments for Python's `websockets` `serve` function

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I am prototyping a WebSocket server using Python's [`websockets` library](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

```py
async def receive_websocket_message(websocket, send_queue: asyncio.Queue, receive_queue: asyncio.Queue):
    async for message in websocket:
        # Send a message to an internal client
        send_queue.put_nowait(message)
        # Wait for a response
        response = await receive_queue.get()
        # Send the response back to the WebSocket sender
        await websocket.send(response)


async def websocket_server(send_queue: asyncio.Queue, receive_queue: asyncio.Queue):
    # How do I pass the queues into the websocket server handler?
    async with serve(receive_websocket_message, "localhost", 8765, send_queue=send_queue, receive_queue=receive_queue):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever
```

How do I pass additional arguments into the [`serve`](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/asyncio/server.html) function, in this case a queue to be shared by the WebSocket server and another internal coroutine?

I get an error like `TypeError: BaseEventLoop.create_server() got an unexpected keyword argument 'send_queue'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out by reading the FAQ and finding an answer there. The solution is to use `functools.partial` to partially evaluate the WebSocket handler function with the extra arguments. In this case, it would look like:

```py
async def websocket_server(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    bound_handler = functools.partial(receive_websocket_message, queue=queue)
    async with serve(bound_handler, "localhost", 8765):
        await asyncio.Future()
```

See the documentation for [How do I pass arguments to the connection handler?](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq/server.html#how-do-i-pass-arguments-to-the-connection-handler).